# Why is the code after my for loop not running?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
<script>
    
    //references the submit button, runs if it is clicked
    const sub = document.getElementById("sub");
    sub.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //references every input number
    var in1 = document.getElementById("in1").value;
    var in2 = document.getElementById("in2").value;
    var in3 = document.getElementById("in3").value;
    var in4 = document.getElementById("in4").value;
    var in5 = document.getElementById("in5").value;
    
    //creates an array and puts all of the inputted values into it
    const inputs = new Array();
    inputs.push(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5);
    
    //references all of the circles
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
    var num3 = document.getElementById("num3");
    var num4 = document.getElementById("num4");
    var num5 = document.getElementById("num5");
    
    //creates an array and stores all of the references to the circles in it
    var circles = new Array();
    circles.push(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    
    //creates an array for the generated numbers
    var generated = new Array();
    
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        //fills the array with 5 random numbers
        let gen = Math.round(Math.random() * 38);
        generated.push(gen);
        //changes the numbers in the circles to the random numbers
        circles[i].innerHTML = generated[i];
    
    }
    
    alert("test");//this doesn't pop up
    
    });
```

All of my code up to this point works perfectly, and the numbers are correctly added to the circles, but then anything I write after the for loop does not run, and I cannot figure out why. If the alert is anywhere else in the code above the for loop, it pops up with no issues.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to make an alert pop up to check if anything was running after the for loop, and it did not pop up.

Comment: Should be `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)`. But better to use `i < circles.length` instead of hardcoding the 5 or 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SME gave you the answer here, the alert never triggers as your code runs and then errors when the loop hits the bad index. Without seeing your HTML I put together this quick demo. It works in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <input type="button" id="sub" value="PUSH ME">
    <input type="text" value="1" id="in1">
    <input type="text" value="1" id="in2">
    <input type="text" value="1" id="in3">
    <input type="text" value="1" id="in4">
    <input type="text" value="1" id="in5">
    <div id="num1"></div>
    <div id="num2"></div>
    <div id="num3"></div>
    <div id="num4"></div>
    <div id="num5"></div>

    <script>

        //references the submit button, runs if it is clicked
        const sub = document.getElementById("sub");
        sub.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            //references every input number
            var in1 = document.getElementById("in1").value;
            var in2 = document.getElementById("in2").value;
            var in3 = document.getElementById("in3").value;
            var in4 = document.getElementById("in4").value;
            var in5 = document.getElementById("in5").value;

            //creates an array and puts all of the inputted values into it
            const inputs = new Array();
            inputs.push(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5);

            //references all of the circles
            var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
            var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
            var num3 = document.getElementById("num3");
            var num4 = document.getElementById("num4");
            var num5 = document.getElementById("num5");

            //creates an array and stores all of the references to the circles in it
            var circles = new Array();
            circles.push(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);

            //creates an array for the generated numbers
            var generated = new Array();

            for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                //fills the array with 5 random numbers
                let gen = Math.round(Math.random() * 38);
                generated.push(gen);
                //changes the numbers in the circles to the random numbers
                circles[i].innerHTML = generated[i];

            }

            alert("test");//this will pop up now

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! This does work, although I am a little confused as to why the circles.length works when 6 doesn't.

Comment: Changing the test to less than 5 would work too, as long as the test is equal to the length of your list  of circles. because you have 5 items, when the loop gets to the number 5 counting from 0 (0,1,2,3,4,5) it is on the 6th index of the list. Because there is no 6th item in the list the loop errors. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah I see! I thought it started at 1 for some reason, despite declaring it as starting at 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a declaration for the `i` variable used in the `for` loop. In JavaScript, it is best practice to declare variables using the `let` or `const` keywords to avoid polluting the global scope.

Try updating your for loop declaration to include let before `i`, like this:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        // your code here
    }
```

It could also be an error within the loop such as an infinite loop or an unhandled exception, which may cause the code after the loop to not execute